# Unable to re-enable location in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

i have a button action in which core location method working

i just want when i don"t allow location and again button click then UIAlertView appears in which it ask again for allow enable location

i don't know what code i put for allow my location again. some one help me

hare is the sample of my source code-

```html
 - (IBAction)geolocation:(id)sender { 
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] &&
       [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        // show the map
       
    NSString *parameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lat=%@&long=%@",lati,longs];
    
    NSURL *url_ = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://***/near_by_api.php"]];
    
    NSData *postData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",parameter] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url_];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    
    if (urlData) {
             
        record = [NSMutableArray array];
        record = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        
        [self.view addSubview:third_view];
        [third_view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [third_tbl_view reloadData];
    }}else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Location Service Disabled" message:@"Allowed location?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    
    
    
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
      //code for cancel
        

    }
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        //Code for ok button
        
        
                   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't allow location, for the next time you have to activate location manually in the settings. You can open settings by this way :

```
if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL) {
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
else {
  // Present some dialog telling the user to open the settings app.
}
```